# Is it possible for applications on VMs to communicate with Hypervisor directly (not through VM Kernel)?

Tags: virtual-machine, communication, virtualization

Assuming this figure:

[image]

Is it possible for line 1 of communication to exist directly as shown in the figure? Does any Hypervisor support this type of behavior? If not, is it possible to change a hypervisor (like KVM) to support this?

I suspect line 2 of communication is possible. But I am not quite sure. So the question also applies to line 2 of communcation as shown in the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For example, using Intel VMX, the vmcall instruction can be used from an application. Any other instruction that is allowed in user mode and causes a VM exit can be used, such as cpuid or a memory access to an unmapped page.

The answers to this question talk about how to add a vmcall handler to KVM. [Implementing a custom hypercall in kvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590843/implementing-a-custom-hypercall-in-kvm)

Comment: Thank you. I will look more into the reference.